# Just started programming (Python), using content of text file (x) to satisfy input() == x

Tags: python, if-statement

Using Python I am trying to get the content of a text file to to be variable x and by using a if statement, create a simple password program through the use of user input which is the s variable. However, when I make the user input 1234 which is the same as the text.txt file, the if statement fails and 'Access Denied' is printed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Here is my code:

print ('Enter Password')
s = input() #goal is to input '1234'
x = open('text.txt','r') #text.txt contains '1234'
print("you typed", s)
if s == x:
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```

Comment: `text.txt` needs to *only* have the characters `1234`. If it has anything else including white space or new lines or whitespace this will fail. Check the value of `x` by printing it out and make sure it's what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

In your version, `x` is a file object. To get the content you need to `read` it. It's a good idea to `strip` the whitespace too

```
print ('Enter Password')
s = input() #goal is to input '1234'
x = open('text.txt','r').read().strip()
print("you typed", s)
if s == x:
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```

But now you have an open file that you can't close (Python will usually do it for you but it's better to start doing these things properly). The usual way would be to use `with`

```
print ('Enter Password')
s = input() #goal is to input '1234'

with open('text.txt','r') as fin:
    x = fin.read().strip()
print("you typed", s)
if s == x:
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```

Now the file is closed automatically at the end of the `with` block (This is called a context manager)

Comment: python is really... really really good at garbage collection ... especially when you just open a file for reading ... solid advice all the same though

Answer (score 0):

The output of `open` assigned to variable `x` will be a file object

Try to print `x`, you will see something like below

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='text.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

For the content of the file you can use `.readline()`. It reads one line from file object.
Then you will have a newline at the end to take care of `.strip()` does the job of removing the newline at the end.

Following code works

```
print ('Enter Password')
s = input() #goal is to input '1234'
x = open('text.txt', 'r').readline().rstrip() #text.txt contains '1234'
print("you typed", s)
print("file content is", x)
if s == x:
    print("Access Granted")
else:
    print("Access Denied")
```